# Ruby beginner: code only repeats 2 times

Tags: ruby

Hey the code I created only repeats 2 times.
After I type the second time "y" for the "continue_question"-method the code only stops.

```
def greeting  
  puts "Hello! Please type your name: "  
  name = gets.chomp.capitalize  

  puts "It is nice to meet you #{name}.  I am a simple calculator application."  
  puts "I can add, subtract, multiply, and divide."  
end  

greeting  

def calculator  

    puts "First number: "  
    @n1 = gets.chomp.to_i  
    puts "Secons number: "  
    @n2 = gets.chomp.to_i  

def calculation
  puts "Type 1 to add, 2 to subtract, 3 to multiply, or 4 to divide two numbers: "
  operation_selection = gets.chomp.to_i  

    if operation_selection == 1  
      @result = @n1 + @n2  
    elsif operation_selection == 2  
      @result = @n1 - @n2  
    elsif operation_selection == 3  
      @result = @n1 * @n2  
    elsif operation_selection == 4  
      @result = @n1 / @n2  
    else  
      puts "Something went wrong!"  
      calculation  
    end  
end  

calculation  

puts "Your Result is #{@result}"  
end  

calculator  

def continue_question  
puts "Do you want to continue? (y/n)"  
continue = gets.chomp.to_s  

if continue == "y"  
  calculator  
  elsif continue == "n"  
  puts "Bye!"  
else  
  puts "What?"  
  continue_question  
end  
end  

continue_question
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not repeat 2 times, it repeats **once**.

The reason is because in your `continue_question` method, you do not tell it to repeat again:

```
def continue_question
  puts "Do you want to continue? (y/n)"
  continue = gets.chomp.to_s

  if continue == "y"
    calculator # <-- This causes it it repeat ONCE!
  elsif continue == "n"
    puts "Bye!"
  else
    puts "What?"
    continue_question
  end
end
```

A quick fix is to re-call the `continue_question` method below that line, to recursively repeat itself:

```
def continue_question
  puts "Do you want to continue? (y/n)"
  continue = gets.chomp.to_s

  if continue == "y"
    calculator
    continue_question # <-- Add this to repeat indefinitely
  elsif continue == "n"
    puts "Bye!"
  else
    puts "What?"
    continue_question
  end
end
```

Comment: You could also consider using `while` or `loop` instead of calling the methods recursively like this. However, that's a larger refactor that's probably beyond the scope of your original question.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `continue_question` only executes once, at the end of your code, but you need to loop until user exits (i.e types `n`).

So simply add a loop inside `continue_question`, for example:

```
def continue_question 
  continue = "y" 

  until continue == "n" do
    puts "Do you want to continue? (y/n)"  
    continue = gets.chomp.to_s  

    if continue == "y"  
      calculator  
    elsif continue == "n"  
      puts "Bye!"  
    else  
      puts "What?"  
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

> Hey the code I created only repeats 2 times.

I think you misunderstand the following:

```
if continue == "y"  
  calculator  
  elsif continue == "n"  
  puts "Bye!"
```

When you call the above function `calculator`, you are still executing the `continue_question` function. So when the `calculator` finishes executing, `continue_question` will finish as well and the program will stop. For the wanted result you can try using a [loop](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm).